# print current selected file name

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using the following function to set the text of a Label to be the file name 
i just picked , but i want to get the name of the file i'm currently selecting before canceling or opening the file from the dialog 
is there any way to do so by using tkinter or any other framework/lib 
here's the code

```
 def pick_csv(self):
     filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
     filelabel.config(text=filename)
     #filelabel should get the name of the selected file 
     #before closing the dialog
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can use the native `askopenfilename` to achieve this. But you can write your own class that inherit from `FileDialog`. It will look ugly and needs some work on the layout.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os

root = Tk()

a = Label(root,text="Waiting for selection")
a.pack()

class CustomDialog(filedialog.FileDialog):
    def __init__(self,master,path=""):
        filedialog.FileDialog.__init__(self,master)
        self.files.bind("<Button-1>",self.set_label)
        self.selected = None
        self.go(path)

    def set_label(self,*args):
        a.config(text=self.files.get(self.files.curselection()))
        self.selected = os.path.join(self.directory, self.files.get(self.files.curselection()))

    def cancel_command(self, event=None):
        self.selected = None
        self.quit()

def click():
    f = CustomDialog(root)
    if f.selected:
        print (f.selected)

b = Button(root,text="Browse",command=click)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```